# How to change the tag value of the CCMenuItemImage?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

I have a `CCMenu` with a series of button added with the code:

```
_viewMenu = [[CCMenu alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < _somearray.count; i++)
    {
        switchViewMI = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage: [_somearray objectAtIndex:i]
                                                 selectedImage: [_somearray objectAtIndex:i]
                                                        target: self
                                                      selector: @selector(switchViewSelected:)];
        switchViewMI.tag = i;
        [_viewMenu addChild:switchViewMI];
    }
```

Which I use `switchViewMI.tag` to identify the function to call.

My question is at a point I want to delete some buttons dynamically, so I have to edit the `tag`. But I am not sure how to access `_viewMenu.item`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with cocos2d v2.1, you can access the menu items with

```
[_viewMenu.children objectAtIndex:i];
```

careful if you iterate children and try to delete at the same time, you will get an exception. If you dont plan to animate the buttons 'disappearing', i would simply remove all menu items from the menu and rerun the logic from scratch for adding and placing them in position.

Comment: Yes, that is what I do at the moment: remove all menuitems and rerun the add method. I thought there might be more elegant solution to this. But I made do with this at the moment.

Comment: Elegance is moot : this all happens between display refreshes, and you never run the risk of being 'interrupted' in flight. Your app users will never see the difference :) .